# Capybara-webkit examples?

Tags: rubygems, integration-testing, capybara

Are there any capybara-webkit examples available online? I've seen presentations, but I am looking for actual code. Is there API documentation I can look at?

Answer (score 1):

API doc is here: http://rubydoc.info/gems/capybara-webkit/0.8.0/frames

For examples see tests in sourcecode: https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/tree/master/spec